# Loading Libtiff in MATLAB R2012a

Tags: matlab, loadlibrary, libtiff

I´m trying to load libtiff 3.9.5 in MATLAB R2012a and the situation is: Matlab says I need a Compiler and Perl. I installed Visual Studio 2010 and perl 5.14.2. mex -setup says Compiler is ok but nothing about Perl. Running loadlibrary I got lots of errors ( input character not valid and unkown variable among them). I found that Matlab looks for shrlib.dll in Windows Systems so I get a libtiff.dll in the Internet, use it and nothing changes. Next I get Big TIFF libtiff 4.1 which has a libtiff.lib and no changes again. As I am new in Matlab I just can´t think of what to do anymore. So I ask if somebody will help me. Many thanks in advance and best regards.

P.S. I put libtiff folder in R2012a directory a made it Current Folder.

Comment: What do mean "trying to load libtiff"? What are you trying to do? Matlab includes libtiff: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/tiffclass.html Why do you need an external version?